# SharePoint REST API call not responding

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rest, site-collection

Working on a project where we are creating a new Site Collection for a department.  We are new to SharePoint.  During our testing we created a Site Collection called Test.  I came to realize that the Test Site Collection was a Sub-Site under our main tenancy.
tenancy.sharepoint.com/Test

I did all my research testing both the REST API and the Search REST API against this Test site.

Example:

tenancy.sharepoint.com/Test/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Publications')/Items?$filter=startswith(Title,'Sail')&$select=Title

This would successfully return the results.
This test site, in the Admin Center, is listed as a Site Collection with the address of 
tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/Test

After having tested various REST calls, I then went and created a New Site Collection for the project we're to be working on.  This is an actual Site Collection that isn't a Sub-Site of our main site.  The Admin Center lists this Site Collection with the address of 
tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/department name
It has a Document App Library module installed with the same name of Publications.

I added a document to the site, but when I execute the same REST API call it just doesn't respond.  It doesn't time out, it just gives a white page.

tenancy.sharepoint.com/department name/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Publications')/Items?$filter=startswith(Title,'Sail')&$select=Title

[image: Browser after submitting the rest call. It is just a white screen]

I tried to use the SharePoint Search Query Tool, which uses the Search REST API.
https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

In the connection area, I enter a SharePoint Site URL of tenancy.sharepoint.com/Test

I'm able to successfully login. I'm able to conduct searches.

If I enter: tenancy.sharepoint.com/department name
It says that the login is successful.  When I conduct a search the Connection section title turns red, and I get a 404 Not Found error.

If I enter tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/department name
I'm able to conduct searches, but the results are pulling documents from the tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/Test Site Collection, and nothing from the department's Site Collection is returned.

What am I missing?

PS: I have a lot of example urls above, and the site only allowed me to have a single link within the question.  So I removed all the https from the URLs.

Comment: Run the REST call via the browser's URL bar, you'll gonna get a XML version of response.

Comment: Apologies for not making that clear, but I am also running the call through a browser.  The first portion of my description of the issue, is what I'm encountering when I use a browser.  I just get a white page, no response from the server, not even a timeout error.

Comment: Our SharePoint Online site, has a Business Essentials license.  I'm wondering if this is some kind of limitation of the Business Essentials license.  There is a feature called "Enterprise Search" that isn't available in the Business Essential license.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debug purpose, use the broswer console.
Identify your REST Call in the console's XHR tab.

If red, REST call returned an error:

> => either query is wrong or SP threw an exception

If not red, REST call returned success, even though it has no results:

> => your query is ok.

**Right-click to open call in a new tab to see xml results on browser, or click to get the full information of it.**[image: .enter image description here]

**click to get the full information of it.**
[image]

**You can also run your REST call in the browser address bar to get a xml response.**

Error:
[image]

Success:
[image]

Comment: Please understand, I am getting NO response, that I can analyze.

I'll update the original post to include a screenshot

Comment: Neither in the console?